# Format date strings in datagrid sort URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datagrid

I have a search form that has date range inputs: (`x to y`). Both `x` and `y` need to be in `MM/DD/YY` format for various reasons. When the Rails controller gets the input from the search form, it takes these strings and converts them to `Date` and `DateTime` objects respectively, both of which are passed to the `DataGrid` model to create the object.

When the page reloads after a search form submission, the DataGrid table will be populated with the items returned from the query. Moreover, as a part of the UI of the app, the values input in the search form are retained (so here, the date values passed are shown in the search form).

The issue arises when you click one of the sort header links on the DataGrid table. The URL created by the DataGrid model uses the `Date` and `DateTime` string representations of the objects, not the original format. So, when you click the sort link, the search form is re-populated with those strings and not the original strings.

Is there a way to have DataGrid use the `Date` and `DateTime` objects when creating the ActiveRecord Relation, but format those strings differently for the sort header URLs?